# Circular Particle Effect in Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame, particles

I'm new to C# and Monogame, and I'm trying to create an effect of a 'psychic' ability, the user will press a key and a circular aura blast will emit from their position. I'm just trying to get the actual blast working before setting up the positions and all that, but my problem is when trying to get all the particles to move out from the origin of a circle to the outside.

I've never worked with circles yet and only with Rectangles so my knowledge of this is very basic. You'll probably recognise the code from a youtube channel and that's because I've been trying to learn from wherever I can, most of the time that leads me to youtube since a video demonstration works best but I digress.

This is my code for the particle generator so far.

```
namespace Particles
{
class ParticleGenerator
{
    Texture2D texture;
    float spawnWidth;
    float density;

    List<Particles> particles = new List<Particles>();

    float timer;

    public ParticleGenerator(Texture2D newTexture, float newSpawnWidth, float newDensity)
    {
        texture = newTexture;
        spawnWidth = newSpawnWidth;
        density = newDensity;

    }

    public void createParticle(GraphicsDevice graphics)
    {

        particles.Add(new Particles(texture, new Vector2(graphics.Viewport.Width / 2 , graphics.Viewport.Height /2), new Vector2(5, 1)));

    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, GraphicsDevice graphics)
    {
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        while (timer > 0)
        {
            timer -= 1f / density;
            createParticle(graphics);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < particles.Count; i++)
        {
            particles[i].Update();
            if (particles[i].Position.Y > graphics.Viewport.Height)
            {
                particles.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach (Particles particle in particles)
        {
            particle.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I would recommend posting this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com, where monogame developers are more likely to see it.

Comment: @SomeGuy Yeah I'll do that, thanks for the info :)